# Updating pandas DataFrame column does not work when iterating through rows in a for loop

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code, through which I am trying to iterate through several .csv files and finding the minimum value of some of the columns (excluding 0 values) for each of the files and then putting these minimum values in a master spreadsheet:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

main = pd.read_csv("main.csv")

for fname in glob.glob("Folder/*.csv"):
    df = pd.read_csv(fname)
    bims = [100, 101, 102, 103]
    for bim in bims:
        for module in range(1, 5):
            column = f"Module {module} Voltage"
            min_v = df[column].loc[df[column] != 0].min()
            main.loc[main["BIM_Number"] == bim, f"M{module}_Vmin"] = min_v
```

where bims is a list of integers indicating which row of the main spreadsheet to update. What this code should do (and it works if I try it for each bim value individually, i.e. not using a loop) is take the minimum value of four columns (Module voltage 1, 2, 3, 4) from the .csv file and append each value in the main dataframe object in columns M1_Vmin, M2_Vmin, M3_Vmin, M4_Vmin respectively). However the code runs fine but in the end the main dataframe is not updated. As I mentioned if I try this by just manually inputting a value from the bim list the main dataframe for the row containing that bim value is updated just fine? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Without any example data, it's difficult to give concrete advice, but it looks like you can (and probably [should](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/15873043)) get rid of the loops and perform the whole operation in one step.

This solution assumes the `M{i}_Vmin` and `Module {i} Voltage` columns are adjacent so you can select them with ranges (note that the ranges are *inclusive* in this case). If they are not adjacent, replace the `"M1_Vmin":"M4_Vmin"` and `"Module 1 Voltage":"Module 4 Voltage"` with lists of the column names or use `.filter`.

```py
main.loc[main["BIM_Number"].isin(bims), "M1_Vmin":"M4_Vmin"] = (df.loc[:, "Module 1 Voltage":"Module 4 Voltage"]
                                                                  .replace(0, pd.NA) # since .min ignores NaN
                                                                  .min().values)
```